# How to build custom object dynamically based on scopes?

Tags: json, go, struct, rpc

I am in a situation where i need to return an list objects based on scopes. These scopes determine the fields inside the object

```
type Test struct {
    A       int64
    B       int64
    C       int64
    D       int64
    E       int64
}
```

Based on the list of scopes, let say if user needs only A,B,C then I should be returning and object with only ABC as fields.

Currently i am building entire object and then using reflect to remove the fields that are not required. Is there a better approach ? I am new to golang

Comment: How do you remove fields using reflect?

Comment: By removing i mean i just add the only field that i care. Basically  you can use reflect to get the struct field and value. Later you can iterate over the object (numfield) and create an object with the fields that you require. This is very naive way.

Comment: There is no way for reflect to add or remove fields.

So you need to generate some code that have all the combinations of fields and pick the one you need from that list.

(or just don't do that, it sounds like you are trying to do something wrong)

Comment: @asdadw - maybe more convenient way is to change `struct` with declared fields to `map`?!

Comment: Since this is json specific you should take advantage of the `,omitempty` option of the json struct tag. And to support zero values you should update the fields to be pointers. https://go.dev/play/p/ON6IXOnWE7k

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this in the first place? This doesn't seem like something you should ever need to do.